# setOnChartValueSelectedListener in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart Android library.

I am facing the issue when I change fragment in setOnChartValueSelectedListener in bar chart.

At the same moment, same code is working in `mChart.setOnClickListener`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        String xAxisValue = mChart.getData().getXVals().get(e.getXIndex());

        Log.d("test", "xAxisValue: " + xAxisValue);

        String check_tab = SPUtiles.getStringValue(BTConstants.CHECK_TAB, "day");
        Utils.getXValue=xAxisValue;
        if (check_tab.equals("year")) {
            mActivity.barClick(R.id.rb_history_tab_month, 2);
        } else if (check_tab.equals("month")) {
            mActivity.barClick(R.id.rb_history_tab_week, 2);
        } else if (check_tab.equals("week")) {
            mActivity.barClick(R.id.rb_history_tab_day, 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

Here is my logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.VelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(int, float)' on a null object reference
at com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.BarLineChartTouchListener.onTouch(BarLineChartTouchListener.java:171)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onTouchEvent(BarLineChartBase.java:640)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8393)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2426)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2749)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8583)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4091)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3957)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5806)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5745)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5716)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your package name in the log. This is probably an error/bug in the library; you should report it on Github.

Comment: @rustedbrain- Yes i know that the bug is in mpchart library and that's why i have tagged mpchart.

Comment: hmm you should report it on github too..